# Fade between images on screen using Python TKinter / imageTK

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am a python newbie and have been making a somewhat odd slideshow script that cycles through images and also sources a variable from another file to 'settle' on an image.

I'm sure my code is tragic. But it does work (see below)!

My question is - how would I make it fade between images instead of the jerky go to white momentarily then to next image which it does currently? Is there a transitions module I should look at?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk, random, string

class MyApp(Tk):

def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)
    fr = Frame(self)
    fr.pack()
    self.canvas  = Canvas(fr, height = 400, width = 600)
    self.canvas.pack()

    self.old_label_image = None
    self.position = 0
    self.command = 0
    self.oldcommand = 0

    self.slideshow()
    self.debug()

def debug(self):
    self.QUIT = Button(self)
    self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT!" + str(self.command)
    self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
    self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

    self.QUIT.pack({"side": "right"})

def slideshow (self):

    if self.command != self.oldcommand:
        self.after_cancel(self.huh)
        # run through random between 2-5 changes 
        # then settle on command for 30 seconds
        self.title("Title: PAUSE")
        self.oldcommand = self.command
        self.slideshow()
    else:
        file = str(self.position) + '.jpg'
        image1 = Image.open(file)
        self.tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        label_image = Label(self, image=self.tkpi)
        label_image.place(x=0,y=0,width=image1.size[0],height=image1.size[1])
        self.title("Title: " + file)

        if self.old_label_image is not None:
            self.old_label_image.destroy()
        self.old_label_image = label_image

        # make this random instead of pregressional
        if self.position is not 1:
            self.position = self.position + 1
        else:
            self.position = 0

        commandfile = open('command.txt', 'r')
        self.command = string.atoi(commandfile.readline())
        commandfile.close()

        int = random.randint(2000, 5000)
        self.huh = self.after(int, self.slideshow)
        #self.after_cancel(huh) - works ! so maybe can do from below Fn?

if __name__ == "__main__":
root = MyApp()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you provide the 'command.txt'? I can't test your code without that. I've tried to delet it but I only see the blue background not my jpg images

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the blend function.

```
 Image.blend(image1, image2, alpha) ⇒ image
```

Creates a new image by interpolating between the given images, using a constant alpha. Both images must have the same size and mode.

```
out = image1 * (1.0 - alpha) + image2 * alpha
```

If the alpha is 0.0, a copy of the first image is returned. If the alpha is 1.0, a copy of the second image is returned. There are no restrictions on the alpha value. If necessary, the result is clipped to fit into the allowed output range.

So you could have something like this:

```
alpha = 0
while 1.0 > alpha:
    image.blend(img1,img2,alpha)
    alpha = alpha + 0.01
    label_image.update()
```

An example is here, havn't had time to test this but you get the idea-

```
from PIL import image
import time
white = image.open("white_248x.jpg")
black = image.open("black_248x.jpg")
new_img = image.open("white_248x.jpg")
root = Tk()
image_label = label(root, image=new_img)
image_label.pack()
alpha = 0
while 1.0 > alpha:
    new_img = image.blend(white,black,alpha)
    alpha = alpha + 0.01
    time.sleep(0.1)
    image_label.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks - this comes at a very timely moment :-) Do you have an example of a script doing this?

Comment: It is in the original question at the bottom- I have edited it :)

Comment: I get the following error with your example (for the line where the Label is declared), in Python 3.x: `_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1366x768 at 0x7F5D3A1C8BA8>" doesn't exist` (the image file does exist, and the variable for it was declared).