# Fading Between Two Images Incorrectly (PIL / Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to add a little flair to my Tkinter using PIL, but I am having an issue where PIL's blend function seems to fade incorrectly to the second image ([example](https://puu.sh/BOnIh.gif)). (PS, Squirtle's the best)

I tried modeling my code based on an answer I found [here in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234402/10534715), but the resulting fade effect is not quite right.

Below is a code snippet of the program for just this issue:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

def RGBAImage(path):
    return Image.open(path).convert("RGBA")

class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        app = App(parent=self, controller=self)
        app.grid(row=0, column=0)

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.alpha = 0

        # combine the base image and the border frame using paste
        self.img_pieces = []
        for i in range(2, 5):
            self.img_pieces.append(RGBAImage("media\\piltest%d.png" %(i)))
        self.img_border = RGBAImage("media\\piltest1.png")
        for i in range(3):
            self.img_pieces[i].paste(self.img_border, (0, 0), self.img_border)

        # use ImageTk to create PhotoImage for Tkinter
        self.images = []
        for i in range(3):
            self.images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img_pieces[i]))

        # establish example images
        self.examples = []
        for i in range(3):
            self.examples.append(tk.Label(self, image=self.images[i]))
            self.examples[i].image = self.images[i]
            self.examples[i].grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="nsew")

        # create "fading" images example
        self.button = tk.Button(self, image=self.images[0], command=lambda:self.fade())
        self.button.image = self.images[0]
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nsew")

    def fade(self):
        # stop fading once alpha == 1 (a.k.a. second image)
        if self.alpha == 1.0:
            return

        # create the interpolated image using the current alpha value
        self.new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.blend(self.img_pieces[0], self.img_pieces[2], self.alpha))
        self.alpha = self.alpha + 0.1

        # update the image displayed continuously to create the "fade" effect
        self.button.config(image=self.new_img)
        self.button.image = self.new_img
        self.after(10, self.fade)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    app = MainApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried with some efforts? Show you work please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by efforts? I managed to narrow down the issue to the if statement:

    if self.alpha == 1.0:

apparently doesn't work, but:

    if self.alpha >1.0:

works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the exit condition:

```
if self.alpha == 1.0:
    return
```

Upon further inspection of how alpha was changing during the after loop, alpha went beyond 1.0 and kept going infinitely, so the code should be changed to the following to properly stop at 1.0:

```
if self.alpha > 1.0:
    return
```